# The way to list subsets of the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} with forest or tree package

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, trees

I want to list the number of subsets of the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. I tried with `forest` package.

```
    \documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{forest}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={edge={->}}
    [\{1;\,2;\,3;\,4;\,5\}[1[2[3[4[5]][5]][4[5]][5]][3[4[5]][5]][4[5]][5]][2[3[4[5]][5]][4[5]][5]][3[4[5]][5]][4[5]][5]]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this diagram, have not the empty set. What is the better way to list?

Comment: Wikipedia suggests a graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#/media/File:Hasse_diagram_of_powerset_of_3.svg

Comment: What are you trying to show exactly? Do you want something like the wikipedia diagram @Marijn mentioned? At first I thought the paths in your tree represented the possible subsets. But {1,2,3,4} is excluded in that case, for example. By the way, why semicolons rather than commas to list elements?

Comment: Yes. I want to something like the wikipedia diagram @Marijn mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another method, which I eventually figured out. Instead of using pure Ti*k*Z, it combines Forest with expl3 functions to construct the contents of all nodes bar the root.

`subsets` initiates the style. `n elements=<integer>` should be used to specify the number of elements in the root subset. The style will then construct the root subset, add the descendants and populate them appropriately. That is,

```
\begin{forest}
  subsets,
  [, n elements=3]
\end{forest}
```

will produce the tree for the root set containing 3 elements

[image: 3 element set]

and

```
\begin{forest}
  subsets,
  [, n elements=5]
\end{forest}
```

that for the set containing 5.

[image: 5 element set]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse,forest}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_subsets_subset_clist
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \subsets_construct_subset:nn
{
  \clist_set:Nn \l_subsets_subset_clist { #2 }
  \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
  {
    \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
    \clist_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_clist \l_subsets_subset_clist
    \clist_clear:N \l_subsets_subset_clist
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
    {
      \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
      \int_compare:nF { ##1 = \l_tmpa_int }
      {
        \clist_put_right:Nn \l_subsets_subset_clist { ####1 }
      }
    }
  }
  \clist_if_empty:NTF \l_subsets_subset_clist
  {
    \emptyset
  }{
    \{ \clist_use:Nn \l_subsets_subset_clist { , } \}
  }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \constructsubset { m m }
{
  \group_begin:
  \subsets_construct_subset:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\forestset{
  declare toks={subset chooser}{},
  declare toks register={root set},
  root set={},
  n elements/.style={
    tempcounta'=0,
    if={>nn={0}{#1}}{content=\emptyset}{
      until={
        >Rn={tempcounta}{#1}%
      }{
        tempcounta'+=1,
        if tempcounta=1{root set=1}{root set+={,}, root set+/.register=tempcounta},
      },
      delay={
        tempcounta'=0,
        while={>Rn<{tempcounta}{#1}}{
          where n children=0{
            tempcountb'=#1,
            tempcountb-/.register=tempcounta,
            repeat/.process={Rw{tempcountb}{##1}{append={[]}}},
          }{},
          tempcounta'+=1,
          do dynamics,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  subsets/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      where level=0{content=\{,content+/.register=root set,content+=\}}{
        temptoksa/.option=n,
        for nodewalk={until={>On={level}{0}}{parent}}{+temptoksa={,},+temptoksa/.option=n,},
        subset chooser/.register=temptoksa,
        TeX/.process={ORw2{subset chooser}{root set}{\xdef\tempa{\constructsubset{##1}{##2}}}},
        content/.expanded=\tempa,
      },
      for tree={
        math content,
        edge+=<-,
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  subsets,
  [, n elements=3]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  subsets,
  [, n elements=5]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's two ways to do it. The first one explicitely constructs every node, based on the information in option `set`. The second is a bit faster, as it constructs a child of the root by copying all the following siblings into it.

--Typesetting the trees is still most time consuming here. And typesetting a tree for the set with more than 9 elements exhausts my 80000 save stack. :-(

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  declare keylist={set}{},
  subsets/.style={
    delay={
      split option={content}{;}{set+},
      content={$\{##1\}$},
      process set
    },
  },
  process set/.style={
    split option={set}{,}{process element}
  },
  process element/.style={
    if={strequal("#1","")}{}{split={#1}{=}{process@element,gobble}}
  },
  process@element/.style={
    set-=#1,
    append/.process=Ow{set}{[#1,set={##1},process set]},
  },
  gobble/.style={},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  subsets
  [1;2;3;4;5]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Second way:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  subsets/.style={
    delay={
      tempkeylista={},
      split option={content}{;}{setup subsets},
      content={$\{##1\}$},
      process keylist register=tempkeylista,
    },
  },
  setup subsets/.style={
    tempkeylista'/.process=Rw{tempkeylista}{do element=#1,delay={##1}}
  },
  do element/.style={
    prepend={[#1,
      tempkeylistb'={},
      for following siblings={
        tempkeylistb/.process=Ow{name}{append'=##1}
      },
      process keylist register=tempkeylistb
      ]},
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  subsets
  [1;2;3;4;5]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I change the set [1;2;3;4;5] by [a; b; c; d; e], then a, b, c, d, e were not mathmode. How can I repair?

Comment: Been trying to do this, but couldn't. (Not all the time, but too much ;-).)

Comment: @toandhsp The easiest way is to use key `math content`. As we have to do it after all the dynamic operations: add `before typesetting nodes={for tree=math content}` to the preamble.

Comment: Got there in the end, though my interface differs from yours a little.

Comment: I do seem to have been trying to answer a different question, though ....

Comment: @toandhsp This is neat. But how does it answer the question? It still doesn't include the empty set.

Comment: My bad. Instead of really reading the question, I was simply eager to automatize getting your diagram. Please unaccept my answer in favour of @cfr's.